# Params not passing to methods in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra, parameters

I am building a Sinatra app and wrote it linearly (no methods) to learn how Sinatra works. Now I am trying to refactor it, but the params from my form submission aren't being passed to the methods. Here are the routes:

```
get '/' do
  erb :index  
end

post '/' do
  session = login(params[:username], params[:password])
  get_courses(session, params[:username])
  erb :index
end
```

And here is index.erb

```
<% if !@courses %>
<form action="/" method="post">
  <input type="text" label="username" name="username">
  <input type="password" label="password" name="password">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
<% end %>

<% if @courses %>
<ul>
  <% @courses.each do |course| %>
  <li><%= course %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
<% else %>
<p>No course data yet.</p>
<% end %>
```

I know the params are being passed to Sinatra because I was able to do a simple puts of them, but I get an "ArgumentError at / wrong number of arguments (0 for 2)" when I try to pass them to the methods.

**Update**

From the same file as the routes, here is the login method:

```
def login(username, password)
  login = Savon::Client.new($LOGIN_WSDL)
  login.http.auth.ssl.verify_mode = :none

  session = login.request(:login) do
    soap.body = { :id => username, :pw => password }
  end

  session.to_hash
end
```

Comment: At which line does the error occur?

Comment: The error occurs at "session = login(params[:username], params[:password])" and "get_courses(session, params[:username])" I can post a gist of the backtrace if you think it will help.

Comment: It's hard to tell what's going on since you haven't included the controller methods you're using (login and get_courses). If the error was wrong number of arguments(2 for 0), then I could make some guesses, but your error says you've supplied 0 arguments for a method definition that requires 2 arguments, and without more information it will be difficult to diagnose your problem

Comment: I've updated the question to include the method.

Comment: I don't think the error is what you think it is.  This gist works just fine, and prints the username/password after "login."  https://gist.github.com/e71006e05d75796ddd8b

Comment: According to the console it's actually running the login method (and I can see the SOAP call get made, and the response) but then it throws the error. The error is _for the method I can see it running in the console_ so now I'm thoroughly confused.

Comment: Simple fix: I had a method **and** a variable using the same name. Changed the method name, fixed the problem. Thanks everyone for your help in guiding me to the answer. Now on to the other problems...

Answer (score 0):

Apologies if this is obvious, but have you defined @courses in any of your methods?

Something like this:

```
def get_courses(session, username)
  # ...
  #some logic to figure out courses based on session and username
  # ...
  @courses = ["Some course", "Another course"]
end
```

Comment: Yes, @courses is defined, but it isn't even getting that far.

Comment: I don't think the issue is Sinatra. In this gist I've modified your login method to only provide a hash (and threw in a simple get_courses method), and it seemed to work ok: [https://gist.github.com/2399831](https://gist.github.com/2399831)

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this locally as well.

I found that, for reasons yet unclear to me, the keys in the `#params` `Hash` are always `Strings` rather than `Symbols`. The Sinatra documentation seems to reflect that the `Hash` is either a `HashWithIndifferentAccess`, or the keys are automatically symbolized as part of the `#params` method.

Not sure if that is the same issue you are experiencing, if it's an unintended behavior or Sinatra, or I'm just bad at reading docs.

Comment: Could be the version of Ruby/Sinatra you're using? Can you convert them to symbols? And can you work ok if you just access them as strings? I know those aren't solutions, I'm just wondering how deep the problem goes.